# Can minimizing sum of the parts under square root make the result much larger?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Assume that we know $\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{a_i} \leq \sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{b_i}$. I am wondering whether there exists a constant $c$ such that for any set of integers $d_i$ the following is true.
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{a_i + d_i} \leq c\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{b_i + d_i}.$$
All $a_i$, $b_i$, and $d_i$ are positive real numbers.

I attempted to tackle the problem using the few inequalities that I was familiar with. I also attempted to come up with counterexamples, but I was unable to produce any reasonable ones because $c$ can be any large constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any nonnegative real numbers $x$ and $y$, note that $\sqrt{x+y} \le \sqrt x+\sqrt y$, and also that $\sqrt x+\sqrt y \le \sqrt 2 \sqrt{x+y}$ (each inequality can be verified by squaring both sides and simplifying). Therefore
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{a_i+d_i} \le \sum_{i=0}^n (\sqrt{a_i} + \sqrt{d_i}) \le \sum_{i=0}^n (\sqrt{b_i} + \sqrt{d_i}) \le \sqrt2 \sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt{b_i +d_i}.
$$
The constant $\sqrt2$ is best possible: take all $b_i=1$, while taking $a_0$ just less than $(n+1)^2$ and $a_1,\dots,a_n$ barely greater than $0$.